# Audio output devices only appear one after the other

Tags: sound, 22.04, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I have a problem with audio out devices in my Ubuntu 22.04 laptop. My computer has one built-in speaker out and a jack port for headphones: when my headphones are disconnected, no audio device appears to be connected at all (not even the laptop's built-in speakers).

When my headphones are connected, they appear to be connected (as "headphones"), however the audio is emitted *only* through the laptop's built-in speakers. I suppose that, following this pattern, if I connected a second headphone, the audio would come from the first headphone, but I can't say this is true.

**TL;DR;** audio comes from built-in speaker when headphone out is selected. and when they are disconnected, no audio device appears.

I have tried killing `pulseaudio -k`, to no effect.